# windbg dump command fails with error 0x8007012b

Tags: windows, windbg, minidump

A customer is attempting to capture a minidump of a hang.  He fires up WindDbg and successfully attaches to the process.  WinDbg displays its header:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.11.0001.404 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
```

and the loaded modules are enumerated.

He enters a dump command:

```
.dump /m c:\problem.dmp
```

It reports:

```
Creating c:\problem.dmp - mini user dump
WriteMemoryFromProcess.Read(0x1f1e000, 0x2000) failed, 0x8007012b
Dump creation failed, Win32 error 0n299
"Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed."
```

Error 0x299 is:
The requested operation could not be completed due to a file system limitation

Any ideas what this means or how to diagnose?

Comment: I asked him and his response was:
"no errors in system events.
a lot of free space on C:.
no errors on C:."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the /mA switch, it was [introduced](http://voneinem-windbg.blogspot.com/2008/11/windbg-version-6103233-is-out-i-still.html) with 6.10.3:

Answer (score 2):

Type **net helpmsg 299**, error 299 is

*Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriteProcessMemory request was completed.*

In winerror.h this is **ERROR_PARTIAL_COPY**

Is the process a 64 bit process?  http://winprogger.com/?p=26 lists several reasons this error may occur.

Comment: It's a 32 bit process but note that the windbg version reports "AMD64" - so I think you're on to something.